# docker-machine: command not found for Mac

Tags: python, docker-machine, fenics

On Mac, I have installed

Python version 3.9

and

Docker 20.10.6

and following the instructions from
https://fenics.readthedocs.io/projects/containers/en/latest/quickstart.html

Now installing the FEniCS Docker script works fine but when using the command

fenicsproject run

in the terminal, it says

/usr/local/bin/fenicsproject: line 81: docker-machine: command not found

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside of your Docker Engine release, it seems you need to [install Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/).

Note that [Docker engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/) and [Docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) are not the same.

Comment: Now it says that "No active host found". Is that a different error or still the same problem?

Comment: According to this [post](https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/cant-run-fenics-after-updating-docker/1269/10), that script you are using is outdated and you can follow the steps [here](https://fenics.readthedocs.io/projects/containers/en/latest/introduction.html#running-fenics-in-docker)